# Can I add localization resources (*.resx) to a .net-core app after it was built?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I've read through all of this:

[.net-core localization fundamentals article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

But I'm not sure if resource-files for usage with globalization can only be used if all targeted translations are present prior to the build of the application.

Can I add resources after the build so that I could serve additional language-packs to my customers with this resource-file-system?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The term that seems important here is **Satellite Assemblies** and the articles about it are sparse.

This is an article that describes it for full-stack (from 2011):

[Introduction to Satellite Assemblies by Andy Gonzales](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/global_developer/2011/07/22/introduction-to-satellite-assemblies/)

Here is an article that describes it for .net-core (newer):

[Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core ~ Technical Insanity](https://sbrakl.wordpress.com/2017/09/12/globalization-and-localization-in-asp-net-core-part-2/)

If someone has better material for understanding the procedure, please append them.
I will try this out and post an update with details in the future.